# Ionic.onGesture - Cannot read property ‘addEventListener’ of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a modal with tabs and i want the tabs to be changed with gestures, with the swipe gesture to be exact.

```
<ion-modal-view style="width: 90%; height: 90%; top: 5%; left: 5%; right: 5%; bottom: 5%; background: none;">
    <div style="background: #fff; width: 100%; height: 100px;">
        <ion-content scroll="false" style="height: 100px;">
            ...
        </ion-content>
    </div>
    <div style="background: #fff; width: 100%; height: 75%; position: relative; margin-top: 15px;">
        <ion-tabs class="tabs-light tabs-icon-top">
            <ion-tab title="Simple View"
                     icon-on="ion-ios7-compose"
                     icon-off="ion-ios7-compose-outline"
                     ng-click="selectSimpleViewTab()">
                <ion-content class="padding" id="simpleView">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-80 col-offset-10">
                            <div class="list">
                                <div class="item">
                                    ...
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-80 col-offset-10">
                            <div class="list">
                                <div class="item">
                                    ...
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    ...
                </ion-content>
            </ion-tab>
            <ion-tab title="Complete View"
                     icon-on="ion-ios7-paper"
                     icon-off="ion-ios7-paper-outline"
                     ng-click="selectCompleteViewTab()">
                <ion-content class="padding" id="completeView">
                    Complete View
                </ion-content>
            </ion-tab>
        </ion-tabs>
    </div>
</ion-modal-view>
```

I've added custom ng-click events to the tabs so I can load in the gesture event handler when the tab is shown (`selectSimpleViewTab()` and `selectCompleteViewTab()`).

```
$scope.selectSimpleViewTab = function(){
    $ionicTabsDelegate.select(0);
    setTimeout(function(){
        ionic.onGesture('swipeleft', function(e){
            console.log('swiping to left');
            $scope.selectCompleteViewTab();
        }, document.getElementById('simpleView'));
    }, 500);
};

$scope.selectCompleteViewTab = function(){
    $ionicTabsDelegate.select(1);
    setTimeout(function(){
        ionic.onGesture('swiperight', function(e){
            console.log('swiping to right');
            $scope.selectSimpleViewTab();
        }, document.getElementById('completeView'));
    }, 500);
};
```

The swiping works perfectly. In my console I can see that `swiping to right` and `swiping to left` is called. However, the scope function, that switches the tabs, doesn't get called (`selectSimpleViewTab()` and `selectCompleteViewTab()`) and results in:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
```

What could be causing this in the scope functions? The gesture function does get called because the console logs the swipes but the tab change doesn't get triggered.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: ionic.onGesture gives this error if you pass a null object to it. Check if document.getElementById('...') is giving you anything - might be that the element isn't rendered yet.